# Ruby custom email headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, smtp, email-headers

I'm trying to send an email with custom headers but for some reason they just don't get through.

When I call my mailing method in the console, my custom parameter is actually listed:

```
<X-SMTPAPI: {"messageid" : "nomnom"}>
```

This is what I'm doing in my code:

```
headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = "{\"messageid\" : \"nomnom\"}"
mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Confirmation"  )
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
The problem seems to be with using `X-SMTPAPI`as key. Using something else does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for specifying headers is as follows:

```
headers({'X-No-Spam' => 'True', 'In-Reply-To' => '1234@message.id'})
```

Looked at [ActionMailer::Base documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html).

Comment: But where do I specify `X-SMTPAPI` than?

Comment: @Sled, look at the above code. @Semyon is setting two headers, `X-No-Spam` and `In-Reply-To`; you just need to substitute those two with your example.

Comment: Looks like you can also do: `default "X-SMTPAPI" => "{\"messageid\" : \"nomnom\"}"`.

Answer (score 0):

The Headers can only be set to perfectly valid JSON.  This should work:

```
headers['X-SMTPAPI'] = '{"thing": "SomeEmail"}'
```